# Android Paging 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging

Trying to upgrade to version 3 of paging and i am starting to have difficulties since importing the library ... seems like it is having conflicts to work side to side of coroutines

```
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)
Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.Active found in modules kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9) and kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9)


    PAGING_VERSION = '3.0.0-alpha07'

  implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:" + PAGING_VERSION
```

Comment: i ended up using paging version '3.0.0-alpha01'

Comment: Btw alpha11 has updated to 1.4.1 so hopefully that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation('androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha11') {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm'
}
```

Just exclude `'kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm'` from paging3.